# CSS flex Property

Tags: css, flexbox

What is the difference between

```
.Grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

and

```
.Grid-cell {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Will both `.Grid-cell` will react the same way?

Comment: what brower are you using?

Comment: @JeroenKnockaert makes a good point.  flex 0 0 100% will be consistent in all browsers.  flex 1 in Chrome gets translated to flex 1 1 0%.  Each browser can handle the shorthand differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex: 0 0 100%;` sets the flex-basis to 100% .

It means: make the flex item take up ***all*** the width ie 100% width of the flex container (assuming default flex direction - row)

flex: 1; sets the flex-grow property to 1. (the default value is 0)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow):

> The flex-grow CSS property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex
>   item. It specifies what amount of space inside the flex container the
>   item should take up.

More specifically: When it is the only flex item with flex-grow set with value 1 - It means fill the ***remaining*** width of the container

> Both Grid-cell will react the same way ?

That would only be the case if there's only one flex item - where 'all the width' = 'all the remaining width'

here's a little demo which show that they are different:

```css
.wpr1, .wpr2 {
  display: flex;
}
.wpr1 .Grid-cell {
  flex: 1;
}
.wpr2 .Grid-cell {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<h4>When there is only one flex item result is the same</h4>
<div class="wpr1">
  <div class="Grid-cell">one</div>

</div>
<hr>
<div class="wpr2">
  <div class="Grid-cell">one</div>
</div>
<h4>When there is more than one flex item result is different</h4>
<div class="wpr1">
  <div class="Grid-cell">one</div>
  <div class="Grid-cell">two</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wpr2">
  <div class="Grid-cell">one</div>
  <div class="Grid-cell">two</div>
</div>
```